# query without loop

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to query from the db records for a single post (title, body, date)

For example I have my query..

`$query = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=$post_id';`

From that query how can I echo the title for instance without a while or foreach loop?

Comment: If it's only returning a single row, what does it matter?

Comment: do you really need everything? (*)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just call mysql_fetch_assoc() (or any similar function) one. Like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc( mysql_query($sql) );
echo $row['title'];
```

This is the easiest and most readable way to do this with the MySQL functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [mysql_result](http://php.net/mysql_result):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=$post_id';
$query = mysql_query($sql);
echo mysql_result($query, 0, 'title');
```

This will echo the field `title`for the first(0) row.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code for select query without using while loop:

$conn is an database connection

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM teacher_details";
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conn->query($sql) );
$teacher_name = $row['teacher_name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use functions like `mysql_fetch_array`, you're not obligated to iterate. Even, when you do it, you're just getting the result of the next row available, until it returns null:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

So, doing this for each row in the query is technically the same:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query)
var_dump($row);
// Array()
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query)
var_dump($row);
// Array()
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query)
var_dump($row);
// null < the "while" statment will stop here
```

Then, you can call `mysql_fetch_array` once and that's it.

Good luck!